# How to convert String from JSON to array of objects in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "PostID": 158,
      "PostText": "post with tag to @fouad.mohsen and @kamix",
      "JSONTags": "[{\"id\": 5, \"nickname\": \"Joe\"}, { \"id\": 18,  \"nickname\": \"Toni\" }]"

}
```

I am receiving this JSON data, I could reach inside it , but "JSONTags" is returned as String, I want to use is it as an array of objects, so I could reach to the nickname of each user.

Comment: use `NSJSONSerialization` for JSONTags

Answer (score -1):

check out that framework https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
let jsonObject = json.arrayObject
```